# Running while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) multiple times

Tags: php, sql-server, while-loop

I am retrieving a couple of tables from a MSSQL database, which I am then running through to obtain order information from.

My code looks like this:

```
    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($orderResult))
    {
        ......code........
        ..................
        while($statusRow = sqlsrv_fetch_array($statusResult))
        {
            ....code....
        }
        ....code....
    }
```

Now my problem is that after the second loop runs through, it never runs again. And I need it to run every time the first loop runs.

Is there anything I can do to reset that second loop to run again?

Thank you in advance. Any help or a push in the right direction will be very helpful.

Comment: Fetch the data to the array and traverse through it instead

Comment: Nested loops seem like a code smell to me. Why doesn't the query have a combined result set so you don't have to loop every row in a loop?

Comment: @zerkms How would I go about doing that? I've been trying to think that through. Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I'm also not very experienced with SQL, so I'll look into that. Thank you!

Comment: To whoever downvoted my question, can you tell me why that was? If it was invalid syntax or some other reason I'd like to know to learn from that. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read about the other parameters in [sqlsrv_fetch_array()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php)

You can do something like this to reset

```
// reset, and get first row
$row = sqlsrv_fetch_row($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_BOTH, SQLSRV_SCROLL_FIRST);

// get second (and nth row) normally
$row = sqlsrv_fetch_row($result);
```

Alternatively, I think you could benefit from doing a `JOIN` in your query to return a single result.  Merging results manually like this seems a little hackish.

Comment: I'm looking into SQL JOIN. I'll check that first before trying more nested loops, since it seems that that's the general consensus. 

I'll let you guys know how it turns out!

Comment: Joins were my answer. Thank you very much. Sometimes it just takes someone to point out the flaws!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when calling a stored proc from a database that returned multiple result sets. I found Macek's answer didn't work for me, but [another answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/eec88358-0c51-4d94-aff1-48bc151cfee1/result-set-metadata-from-ctp-php-driver-feedback?referrer=http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/eec88358-0c51-4d94-aff1-48bc151cfee1/result-set-metadata-from-ctp-php-driver-feedback?forum=sqldriverforphp) did:

```
$resultSet = array();
$isNotLastResult = true;
$i = 0;

while (!is_null($isNotLastResult))
{
    $resultSet[$i] = array();

    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        $resultSet[$i][] = $row;
    }

    $isNotLastResult = sqlsrv_next_result($result);
    $i++;
}

print_r($resultSet);
```

PS: I gave you an up arrow to counteract your down arrow. You asked a question I spent quite a bit of time looking for the answer to. Good question!

Answer (score 1):

Use the following to reset the pointer:

```
sqlsrv_fetch_array ($Res, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC, SQLSRV_SCROLL_ABSOLUTE, -1);
```

Then use the same code as before to loop through the result set. sql_fetch_array appears to increment the pointer after retrieving the data. Requesting the -1 record retrieves nothing but then sets the pointer to 0 which is the first record.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure your second loop got results for a second run ? maybe, if your $statusResult depents on your $row and your $row has just entries for the first loop you should insert some pseudo-entries to your db.

the second loop should refresh itself in the next "big" loop cause the whole inner block will be destroyed at the end of the big block and will be (fully) rebuild at the next entry.