# how to put a record set back to the first row for sqlsrv_fetch_array

Tags: php

I have a recordset retrieved succesfully by a call to sqlsrv_query.

I can loop through it like so:

```
$rsult = sqlsrv_query($dbconn, $SqlStatement_tmp);
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($rsult, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC))
  print $row[1];
```

that works as it should.

My question is: How do I put the record set at the beginning again?  So I can loop through it again.

Comment: Accepted answer will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10524263/running-whilerow-sqlsrv-fetch-arrayresult-multiple-times